# Linq Expression Query with In clause

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert this SQL query into a LINQ query

```
select s.[Value],
       d.[Value]
  from [ddm].[FieldValueMapping] m
 inner join[ddm].[FieldValue] s on m.SourceFieldValueId = s.FieldValueId
 inner join[ddm].[FieldValue] d on m.DestinationFieldValueId = d.FieldValueId
 where m.SourceFieldValueId in (select FieldValueId from[ddm].[FieldValue] where FieldId = 17)
```

I did this so far but I don't know how to include the "in" condition

```
var values = (
     from m in context.FieldValueMappings
     join s in context.FieldValues on m.SourceFieldValueId equals s.FieldValueId
     join d in context.FieldValues on m.DestinationFieldValueId equals d.FieldValueId
     where (m.SourceFieldValueId.());
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: linq will convert the basic `in` (ie Enumerable.Contains) operator to a database in so aslong as your source value can be linq'ed to a sql source the convertion will be made in linq2sql

Comment: ok thanks but I don't know how to write that query in linq